# wamp mysql user creation - root required localhost but normal user need ipaddress to access

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have windows 8 Setup & Wampserver 2.1 is installed couple of days back.

I execute following sql from command prompt. (assume my ip address is 23.34.54.78),

mysql --port=3306  --host=localhost  --user=root --password=abcd -e "CREATE USER test1 IDENTIFIED BY 'test1'";

it create user test1,  but to access this user it required  host as 23.34.54.78
& does not work for localhost.

is there any issue in config?

[ I have another setup where wamp is installed & on that server everything is working fine ].
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to enforce a domain of localhost:-

```
CREATE USER 'test1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'a Strong Password'
```

Or to be allowed to login from anywhere

```
CREATE USER 'test1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'a Strong Password'
```